# mod_rewrite in .htaccess causing directories to lead to error 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been modifying my website URLs in order to beautify them a bit, but I'm currently having an issue regarding to the site directories.

For instance, my links look like `users/[user_id]/` instead of `users.php?p=[user_id]`. Everything is working well apart of the directories, as said above.

When I try to access, for instance, to `www.mywebsite.com/js/`, I'm facing an error 500 from the server, which, hypothetically, means that there is no file/directory with this name, because of the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` line.

Here is the code I've put in my `.htaccess`file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)/?$ /user.php?p=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/?$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Error Documents Redirect
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mywebsite.com/notFound/
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mywebsite.com/forbidden/
ErrorDocument 401 http://www.mywebsite.com/unauthorized/

# Options
Options All -Indexes
Options All +FollowSymLinks
```

I don't really understand, as I just started working on this for the first time like a few hours ago, and I just start to understand the regex, and path formatting.

I hope you'll be able to help me, and through this, help people facing this issue too.

Regards

Comment: 500 is for error in page on server 404 for not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(css|js)/

below

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/?$1 [L,R=301,NC]

please put this and check

and this after

RewriteEngine On

// having this rule in place we can remove the upper mentioned rule as apache will stop processing other conditions when see this rule

RewriteRule ^(css|jss)($|/) - [L]

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! But now I'm having the same error, but for their files and sub-directories and I am not pretty sure about the way to fix it. Does a RewriteCond with both the folder paths and /*.* proceeding operator or something like this work? Is there a way to cope with both the directories and their content no matter the file extensions or the number of sub-dirs?

Comment: I've make changes in mine answer

Comment: Thank you so much @Mohtisham, it works as intended, I really appreciate your help!